# Detect which open Matplotlib figure is selected

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, pyqt4

Hopefully there is a simple solution to this but I am trying to detect which figure is currently active i.e. when a user clicks on a specific figure when multiple figures are open a variable should be updated storing which figure was selected.

The figures are created by users via a GUI.

Answer (score 0):

To get the current figure you can use:

```
plt.gcf()
```

**Note**: `gcf` stands for *get current figure*

Comment: I am firing an event every time the user clicks on the figure. gcf() returns the current figure however when multiple figures are open it returns the same value when clicking on each one

Comment: Well then you should add your code. And not just all of it (since this is gui related there is probably a lot of code involved). Create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Shouldn't the callback function for the click event receive an argument which tells you which figure it came from?